# Saving a generated barcode using the Zend library in Codeigniter

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, zend-framework, barcode

Wonder if anyone can help,

I'm using the Zend barcode library inside codeigniter to automatically generate barcodes, this is working fine when I visit the URL but I would like to save the image as a jpeg on the server, however this doesn't seam to be working aka it wont create the image,

I'm using the URL as the image source via the codeigniter image class,

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this problem in other way.

```
$config = new Zend_Config(array(
    'barcode'        => 'code39',
    'barcodeParams'  => array('text' => 'TestCode', 'barHeight'=>30, 'factor'=>2),
    'renderer'       => 'image',
    'rendererParams' => array('imageType' => 'gif'),
));

$barcode = Zend_Barcode::factory($config);

imagegif($barcode->draw(), 'barcode-img/barcode.gif');
```

File put contents does not do the trick

Comment: I had to use the same method. Here it is updated for Zend 2.0 (see [Zend Docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.barcode.objects.html) for documentation): 
    
`$imageResource = Zend\Barcode\Barcode::draw(
 'code128', 
 'image', 
 $barcodeOptions, 
 $rendererOptions
);
   
imagepng($imageResource, $imageFilename);`

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is write the image to a file.

```
$imageResource = Zend_Barcode::draw('code39', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions);
file_put_contents($filename, $imageResource);
```